# Order of channels in PIL Image

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

Here is a test code:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image


img = np.ones((2,2,3), np.uint8)
img[:,:,0] = 1
img[:,:,1] = 2
img[:,:,2] = 3

print('img.shape', img.shape)
print('img.dtype', img.dtype)

a = Image.fromarray(np.copy(img).astype(np.uint8)).convert('RGB')
b = Image.fromarray(np.copy(img).astype(np.uint8))
c = Image.fromarray(np.copy(img[:,:,::-1]).astype(np.uint8))

print('a:', np.asarray(a))
print('b:', np.asarray(b))
print('c:', np.asarray(c))

print('np.array_equal(a,b):', np.array_equal(a,b))
print('np.array_equal(a,c):', np.array_equal(a,c))
```

Output:

```
img.shape (2, 2, 3)
img.dtype uint8
a: [[[1 2 3]
  [1 2 3]]

 [[1 2 3]
  [1 2 3]]]
b: [[[1 2 3]
  [1 2 3]]

 [[1 2 3]
  [1 2 3]]]
c: [[[3 2 1]
  [3 2 1]]

 [[3 2 1]
  [3 2 1]]]
np.array_equal(a,b): True
np.array_equal(a,c): False
```

why `.convert('RGB')` is not changing order of channels?

Comment: `fromarray` is already creating an RGB image, so the conversion won't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

The `PIL` image loaded with `fromarray` is stored as RGB, only if you read/load image data with `cv2` aka OpenCV, it is stored with BGR ordering as you probably expect.